# find, printf and odd behaviour with ssh

Tags: ssh, find, printf

So, this works:

```
find /dir/ -type f -printf "%p|%TY-%Tm-%Td|%TH:%TM|%s|%u|%U\n" > /dir/output.txt
```

But this doesn't:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "servername" find /dir/ -type f -printf "%p|%TY-%Tm-%Td|%TH:%TM|%s|%u|%U\n" > /dir/output.txt
```

When run through the ssh command, I get the following errors:

```
bash: %TY-%Tm-%Td: command not found
bash: %TH:%TM: command not found
bash: %s: command not found
bash: %u: command not found
bash: %Un: command not found
```

Is there something specific with reformatting this command that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there something specific with reformatting this command that I'm missing?

Yes.  You lose one level of quoting when you execute a command via ssh.  So this:

```
find /dir/ -type f -printf "%p|%TY-%Tm-%Td|%TH:%TM|%s|%u|%U\n"
```

Becomes:

```
find /dir/ -type f -printf %p|%TY-%Tm-%Td|%TH:%TM|%s|%u|%U\n
```

Which is a bunch of shell commands tied together with pipes (`|`).  You can fix this by putting the whole thing in single quotes:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "servername" 'find /dir/ -type f -printf "%p|%TY-%Tm-%Td|%TH:%TM|%s|%u|%U\n"' > /dir/output.txt
```

Or by passing in your script as stdin to bash instead:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "servername" bash <<EOF > /dir/output.txt
find /dir/ -type f -printf "%p|%TY-%Tm-%Td|%TH:%TM|%s|%u|%U\n"
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'd literally just figured this out a few moments before you posted. I was confused, because sending a ps -efl command didn't require such scrutiny, but of course that's because there's no need for quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on a postcard is...prefix and suffix the original command with a single quote, like this:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "servername" 'find /dir/ -type f -printf "%p|%TY-%Tm-%Td|%TH:%TM|%s|%u|%U\n" > /dir/output.txt'
```